# Graph connected, exists a path containing at least one vertex of each of the four colors.

Tags: graph-theory, trees, coloring, graph-connectivity

I am trying to prove that if G is a 2-connected graph of order 4 or more such that each
vertex of G is colored with one of the four colors red, blue, green, and yellow
and each color is assigned to at least one vertex of G, then there exists a path
containing at least one vertex of each of the four colors.

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: No, I think it's not proper coloring. I was trying to do it by contradiction, but I'm not sure

Comment: If the entire graph is a cycle with $x,y$ in the cycle colored with colors 1,2 and vertices in left path of $xy$ of the cycle is colored with color 3 and the vertices in right path of $xy$ the cycle colored with color 4, will it satisfy ur theorem ? So is ur question , some arbitrary path without fixing end points $x,y$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Assume that colors have numbers 1,2,3,4.
Here are some hints.

1. It is known that for any three vertices $x,y,z$ of a $2$-connected graph there exists a $xy$-path passing through $z$.
2. Obviously, there exists an edge whose vertices are colored differently.
3. Choose an edge $ux$ ($u,x\in V(G)$) whose vertices are colored 3 and 4. Let the vertex $x$ have color 3 and let $y$ and $z$ be arbitrary vertices of colors 1 and 2.
   It follows from (1) that there exists a $xy$-path $P$ passing through $z$.
4. If $u\in P$, then the path $P$ contains vertices of each of the 4 colors, if $u\not\in P$, then the sought path is $uP$.